# Apache Thrift - Compression of Matrix (float arrays) Data Structures?

Tags: c#, networking, io, thrift

I am experimenting with using Apache Thrift to send large amounts of numerical (matrix array) data from a Linux server to a Windows client (C#). The basic data structure is a 2D float array, which could very wel l be sparse. In total, the datasets are large - say on the order of gigabytes.

Does Thrift (using either the TBinaryProtocol or TCompactProtocol) compress the data before sending it? Because I am looking at trying to visualize "slices" of the data in real time, speed is important. I was wondering if there is anyway to compress this data before sending it?

Thanks!

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com) If you can tell us what you've tried to do, why it didn't work, and how it should work, we can help you answer your question

Comment: Currently, I am just using TBinaryProtocol. Should I compress the data via a 3rd party library like a Lempel-Ziv or a "DEFLATE" method and then send it via Thrift? Or does Thrift have any natural addons/extensions that might do this already?

Answer (score 0):

There is a [TZlibTransport](https://github.com/apache/thrift/blob/master/lib/cpp/src/thrift/transport/TZlibTransport.h), which unfortunately is only available for a few language bindings, such as C++. The binary and compact protocols do not compress data.

So either you try to write (contribute?) such a transport for C#, or you simply compress the data before and after.

It is recommended to use `binary` instead of `list<byte>` for large binary data, if you don't do this already. However, if the matrix is sparse, it may be much better to just send the non-empty cells over the wire. It depends on your case.